# I'm having trouble viewing user comments in Flutter with Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I'm trying to sort the user's comments on his profile page but the code doesn't work right what's wrong here please

```
List<Widget> myComments = [];
posts.data.docs.forEach((post) {
  cloudRef.collection('blog').doc(post.id).collection('comments').where('ownerID',isEqualTo:id).get().then((val){
    val.docs.forEach((comment) {
      myComments.add(CommentCard(replyContent: comment.data())); 
    }); 
  }); 
}); 
return myComments;
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with the code is that `forEach` is used with an asynchronous operation. `forEach` does not wait for the async operations to complete for each loop.

Checkout this update to the code using `for-in`. I also updated the comment card list to use `.map` so you can have it in one list and then add all the comments at once.

```dart
List<Widget> myComments = [];

for (var post in posts.data.docs) {
  var val = await cloudRef.collection('blog').doc(post.id).collection('comments').where('ownerID',isEqualTo:id).get();
  var commentCardList = val.docs.map((comment) => CommentCard(replyContent: comment.data())).toList();
  myComments.addAll(commentCardList);
}

return myComments;
```